# Twisted Librarys for IronPython

Tags: twisted, ironpython

I am planning on porting an Python 2.7 App over to IronPython 2.7+

I saw in 2009 that it was being worked on...did this get finished ?

Or do the twisted librarys work on IronPython...is there a work around or should I stop now ??

Thanks In Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Twisted has not been ported to IronPython yet.  You can get a good sense of what platforms Twisted supports by checking out its continuous integration system: http://buildbot.twistedmatrix.com/boxes-supported?branch=trunk&num_builds=10

Answer (score 0):

I doubt Twisted will work on IronPython without some major work. Twisted is pretty complicated. Unless somebody tries it, though, it'll never happen.